# How to communicate object changes via Flux to Websockets in Sping MongoDB Reactive

Tags: flutter, websocket, spring-webflux, spring-websocket, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

Please, give some hint regarding the following!

Pre-requisites:

- Mongo cluster of replica-set type
- `@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories` is in place and all the repositories extend from `ReactiveMongoRepository`
- `@EnableWebFluxSecurity` is in place, there is also a custom filter for Firebase authentication
- Websocket connection is established from Flutter UI via SocketIO-type client (not a SockJS one)

I have a following flow (hereinafter i obfuscate the real classname with `SomeClass`):

- SocketIO subscription from UI is done via `WebSocketHandler` implementation - it basically queries one object from Mongo given unique ID (only one item is expected). The code of handler method is pretty simple:

```
   @Override
   public Mono<Void> handle(org.springframework.web.reactive.socket.WebSocketSession session) {
       return session.send(getUserId(session).flatMap(id -> service.findByUserId(id))
               .map(item -> wrapResponse(item, session)));
   }
```

Code within service class is also straightforward:

```
    public Mono<SomeClass> findByUserId(String userId){
        return repository.findSomeClassByUserId(userId);
    }
```

- there is also a REST endpoint which i call with a PUT request to modify the object in the Mongo DB.
  The code of REST endpoint is pretty simple too:

```
@PutMapping("someclass")
    public Mono<SomeClass> saveProfile(@RequestBody SomeClass payload){
        return service.saveSomeClass(payload);
    }
```

The question is:

- **Is there any way how i can communicate the changes done in the REST call to the given object over the already established WebSocket session?**

Considerations and assumptions:

- I was thinking about change streams - but it works better with SockJS `sendToUser`. Speaking about SocketIO - in this case there needs to be a registry of active sessions which really makes the profit of using reactive style miserable
- `@Tailable`, as far as i understand, has a large limitation - only used for capped collections, which makes it impossible to use.

Guys, any advice and input is highly appreciated!
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Please dont describe your code, instead include enough code with a small example of what you want to establish, ask about. Voted to close, lack of debugging details.

Comment: @Toerktumlare, thank you for your response! Can you, please, be a bit more specific about "what you want to establish"? 
As i said: I want to make changes to an entity in database and want them to be propagated to the UI without using events/listening to anything etc. via reactor functionality. That's it more or less

Comment: @Toerktumlare, and yes - trying to describe the code i wanted to mitigate possible replies like - read the docs. I've read them but there is not much about particular usage of websockets (non-SockJS ones) and Spring Mongo Reactive - therefore, maybe someone might be having some relevant experience. I just wanted to give some context

Answer (score 0):

The only way i have found so far is to use the change streams provided by Spring Data MongoDB